# Magento 1.9 error Table 'magento_oldagain.adminnotification_inbox' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.9, database, migration

i am trying to import Magento database in PHPMYADMIN. I have exported the database using the PHPMYADMIN. I am receiving this error message when i try to import the magento database. How should i fix this error.  any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

**MySQL said: Documentation  #1146 - Table 'magento_oldagain.adminnotification_inbox' doesn't exist**

```
INSERT INTO `adminnotification_inbox` (`notification_id`, `severity`, `date_added`, `title`, `description`, `url`, `is_read`, `is_remove`) VALUES
(1, 4, '2008-07-24 23:54:40', 'Magento 1.1 Production Version Now Available', 'We are thrilled to announce the availability of the production release of Magento 1.1. Read more about the release in the Magento Blog.', 'link is here', 0, 0),
(2, 4, '2008-08-02 00:00:16', 'Updated iPhone Theme is now available', 'Updated iPhone theme for Magento 1.1 is now available on Magento Connect and for upgrade through your Magento Connect Manager.', 'link is here', 0, 0),
(3, 3, '2008-08-02 00:10:27', 'Magento version 1.1.2 is now available', 'Magento version 1.1.2 is now available for download and upgrade.', 'link is here', 0, 0),
(4, 3, '2008-08-1[...]
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `adminnotification_inbox` table present in your database ?

Comment: Yes it exist in the table from which i have exported database

Comment: Please ensure that your table is getting created in your script before the lines you pasted ?

Comment: Hello, Phpmyadmin only exporting insert command not the create table command what should i do. How can i show you images of my current problem. i am only seeing insert sql command in exported table file. Please help!

Comment: In process of export, you have the option to export table structure as well as data. Make sure you are using that.

Comment: I don't know but phpmyadmin is exporting data in html format. I am having this problem for the first time.  Here is the code which i am getting in .sql file when i select structure option in phpmyadmin `code`'<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr' class='chrome chrome48'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><style id' `code`

Comment: Are you aware about `mysqldump` and `mysql` console utility?

Comment: Why you export your database using `phpmyadmin`. Please check out my answer for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to export your database using `mysqldump` console utility:

> mysqldump -u root -p --compress  --disable-keys --quick DATABASE_NAME > /your/path/database_dump.sql

Then import your database using `mysql` command:

> mysql -u root -p YOUR_NEW_DB_NAME < /your/path/database_dump.sql

Note: Please change your `root` with your database `username`.

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Oh my god, it is working after exporting and importing sql database file using the command prompt.  Many many thanks to you sir. it solved my problem.  I have wasted all my day today figuring out this issue. lastly i tried your suggested steps.

Comment: Great, happy coding .... :)